# Porting HP ALM Automatic tests

Tags: hp-alm

We're looking to move away from HP ALM QC. We're looking at the feasibility of being able to port some of the automatic tests we already have in there as we have 1000s. I personally am not familiar with HP ALM as it was used prior to my arrival, as I'm told, it all done through a GUI and backed with XML. I expect there must be some code that is run to execute the scripts, so I'm wondering on the available options if any in obtaining the code for automatic tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base from our project experience I cann tell you the following:

Our test cases are defined in HP ALM and automatic test cases also in HP UFT. After a couple of years we decided to move away from HP ALM and trying to find a solution for transferring the automatic test cases into another test automation tool. In this case we used Saucelabs and Selenium. In Selenium and Saucelabs we wrote the test cases in Java, hence HP UFT is written in VBScript we had unfortunately no chance just to transfer or migrate the test cases in Saucelabs and/or selenium. Furthermore HP ALM is a Standalone product. We wrote mostly of the test casese completely new directly in Saucelabs /Selenium, this was much work.

But did you already had made the decision which tool you want to use for test automation? For my understanding only tricentis - a commercial product (you have to pay licence for it) - has the ability to port the test cases from HP ALM to tricentis [Tricentis UFT](https://www.tricentis.com/resources/save-your-hp-uft-selenium-test-cases-in-tricentis-tosca/) At the moment I don't know any other test tool which fits your needs (obtaining test cases UFT and port them to another test automation tool).

Maybe it helps in your case.